# Spring Recebimento de Json Customizado

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

Olá, galera. Tudo bem?

Atualmente no meu sistema eu estou mapeando os objetos de forma padrão do Spring, mas gostaria de fazer um mapeamento customizado:

### Controlador atual

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Bloquete> create(@RequestBody Bloquete obj) {
    Bloquete objAtualizado = repository.save(obj);
    return new ResponseEntity<Bloquete>(objAtualizado, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

### Request atual

```
{
    "cedente":{"id":40,"nome":"Empresa","documentoIdentificacao":"06789233133"},
    "contaBancaria":{"id":14,"agencia":"0400","conta":"9424283"},
}
```

### Request desejada

```
{
    "cedente":40,
    "contaBancaria":14,
}
```

### Response atual e desejado

```
{
    "id":17382173
    "cedente":{"id":40,"nome":"Empresa","documentoIdentificacao":"06789233133"},
    "contaBancaria":{"id":14,"agencia":"0400","conta":"9424283"},
}
```

### Conclusão

A ideia é que quem está enviando o request **não** tenha que ter as informações do objeto apenas o seu id mas sem fazer isso:

```
{
    "cedente":{"id":40},
    "contaBancaria":{"id":14},
}
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode customizar o Serializer  . O código abaixo utiliza a api [Jackson Json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.7.5):

```
import java.io.IOException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
    public class BloqueteSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Bloquete> {
      @Override
      public void serialize(Bloquete bloquete, JsonGenerator jG, SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException,JsonProcessingException {
        jG.writeStartObject();
        jG.writeNumberField("cedente", bloquete.getCedente().getId());
        jG.writeNumberField("contaBancaria", bloquete.getContaBancaria().getId());
        jG.writeEndObject();
      }
    }
```

e o  deserialize

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
public class BloqueteDeserialize extends JsonDeserializer<Bloquete>{
    @Override
    public Bloquete deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext arg1)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
        Bloquete bloquete = new Bloquete();
        bloquete.setCedente(new Cedente); 
        bloquete.getCedente.setId(node.get("cedente").asInt())
        bloquete.setContaBancaria(new ContaBancaria);
        bloquete.getcontaBancaria.setId(node.get("contaBancaria"));
        return bloquete;
    }
}
```

e na entidade adiciona as anotações:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
@JsonDeserialize(using = BloqueteDeserialize.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = BloqueteSerializer.class)
public class Bloquete {

}
```

caso não queria alterar a customização do json, acho que poderia criar uma classe de request, não sei se seria uma boa prática fazer isto.

```
public class BloqueteRequest{
      private int cedente;
      private int contaBancaria;
  }
```

e no método preencheria esta classe

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody Bloquete obj) {
      Bloquete objAtualizado = repository.save(obj);

      BloqueteRequest br = new BloqueteRequest();
      br.setCedente(objAtualizado.getCedente.getId());
      br.setContaBancaria(objAtualizado.getContaBancaria.getid());


      return new ResponseEntity<BloqueteRequest>(br, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
```

Comment: Eu quero mandar "cedente":1 e receber "cedente":{id:1,...}. Acredito que no seu exemplo ele faça o inverso. disso

Comment: atualizei a resposta

Comment: Já marquei sua resposta como a correta, pois realmente é isso que eu quero. Mas estou com problema na hora de fazer o request. Sempre está dando o erro. Quando busco os bloquetes dá "fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException" e quando tento criar um bloquete dá "Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException". Alguma sugestão?

Comment: implementa apenas o JsonSerialize. vc retorna o objeto em outro response?  vc já utilizava o jackson json?

Comment: Postei outra pergunta com o que está acontecendo. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138346/spring-jackson-json-problema-no-deserialize