# Spring/Jackson Json - Problema no deserialize

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Esta pergunta é uma continuação de outra pergunta, um usuário respondeu encontrou a solução para minha outra dúvida ([Spring Recebimento de Json Customizado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137446/spring-recebimento-de-json-customizado)), mas estou agora com problema no mapeamento usando Jackson.

Estou querendo receber um request customizado em JSON e enviar um response "padrão"(do Spring) em JSON.

### Exemplo

Request

```
{
    "codigo":1234,
    "cedente":1,
    "contaBancaria":1,
    "sacado":{
        "nome":"Victor",
        "documentoIdentificacao":"0000000",
        "endereco":"Endereço..."
        }
}
```

Response

```
{
  "id": 46,
  "codigo": 1234,
  "cedente": {
    "id": 1,
    //...
  },
  "contaBancaria": {
    "id": 1,
    //...
  },
  "sacado": null
}
```

### A Dúvida

Como mapear o objeto "Sacado" que é um objeto **Embedded** da classe Bloquete.

```
@Embeddable
public class Sacado {
    private String nome;
    private String documentoIdentificacao;
    private String endereco;
    //Getters e Setters
}
```

### Deserializer (atualmente)

```
public class BloqueteDeserialize extends JsonDeserializer<Bloquete> {
    @Override
    public Bloquete deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext arg1)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
    Bloquete bloquete = new Bloquete();

    JsonNode nodeCodigo = node.get("codigo");
    if(nodeCodigo != null){
        bloquete.setCodigo(nodeCodigo.asLong());
    }
    JsonNode nodeCedente = node.get("cedente");
    if (nodeCedente != null) {
        bloquete.setCedente(new Cedente());
        long idCedente = nodeCedente.asLong();
        bloquete.getCedente().setId(idCedente);
    }
    JsonNode nodeContaBancaria = node.get("contaBancaria");
    if (nodeContaBancaria != null) {
        bloquete.setContaBancaria(new ContaBancaria());
        long idContaBancaria = nodeContaBancaria.asLong();
        bloquete.getContaBancaria().setId(idContaBancaria);
    }
    JsonNode nodeSacado = node.get("sacado");
    if (nodeSacado != null){
    }


    return bloquete;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem que ser obrigatoriamente usando Jackson?

Comment: Posta sua classe bloquete, talvez esse Deserializer seja desnecessario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá seu Deserialize ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
public class BloqueteDeserialize extends JsonDeserializer<Bloquete> {
@Override
public Bloquete deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext arg1)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
    Bloquete bloquete = new Bloquete();

    JsonNode nodeCodigo = node.get("codigo");
    if(nodeCodigo != null){
        bloquete.setCodigo(nodeCodigo.asLong());
    }
    JsonNode nodeCedente = node.get("cedente");
    if (nodeCedente != null) {
        bloquete.setCedente(new Cedente());
        long idCedente = nodeCedente.asLong();
        bloquete.getCedente().setId(idCedente);
    }
    JsonNode nodeContaBancaria = node.get("contaBancaria");
    if (nodeContaBancaria != null) {
        bloquete.setContaBancaria(new ContaBancaria());
        long idContaBancaria = nodeContaBancaria.asLong();
        bloquete.getContaBancaria().setId(idContaBancaria);
    }

    //Parte alterada do seu código.
    JsonNode nodeSacado = node.get("sacado");
    if (nodeSacado != null){
        Sacado sacado = new Sacado();
        sacado.setNome(nodeSacado.get("nome").asText());
        sacado.setDocumentoIdentificacao(nodeSacado.get("documentoIdentificacao").asText());
        sacado.setEndereco(nodeSacado.get("endereco").asText());

        bloquete.setSacado(sacado);

    }

    return bloquete;
}
```

}

Comment: Existe alguma forma "automatizada" de fazer isso? Ou apenas dessa maneira pegando cada atributo da classe e setando no node?

Comment: Olá, existe uma outra forma pode tentar assim também:

`Sacado sacado = new ObjectMapper().treeToValue(nodeSacado, Sacado.class)`

Comment: Se foi util para você a resposta não esqueça de marcar a resposta como util e como melhor resposta, bons estudos :)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado! :)